# php-Ordering an SQL Select statement using value from a drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am trying to Order an SQL select query depending on what the user selects from a drop down list. Here is the code of the list

```
<select name="order">
  <option value="Patients_name">Name</option>
  <option value="Patients_age">Age</option>
  <option value="Patients_address">Address</option>
</select>

$ord=$_POST['order'];#taking the value from the list
$query="Select * from Patients ORDER BY '$ord'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

If i replace

```
$query="Select * from Patients ORDER BY '$ord'";
```

by 
`$query="Select * from Patients ORDER BY Patients_age";`

**Patients_name,Patients_address**
It perfectly works though printing $ord would give me the correct value.
Any idea why it is not taking the value of $ord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY expects a column name. By putting it in quotes, you're making it a string. Remove the single quotes around `$ord`.

By the way, what you're doing is incredibly dangerous and open to SQL injection. You should verify the column submitted is in fact a column and allowed.

Comment: Thank you,i've searched all over and couldn't find anything.
And i don't have to worry about security for now.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put $org within `''`.

`$query = "Select * from Patients ORDER BY $ord";`